# How to fix this CSS advanced positioning issue?

Tags: css, positioning, display, onhover

I am creating a website and am working on a hover animation for CSS.

```
<html> 
...
<body>
<div id ="outer_container">
    <div id="inner_container">
        <img id="imageOne"/>
    </div>
</div>
...

</body>
<html>
```

`outer_container` takes up the width of the page

`inner_container` is a child of `outer_container` and is aligned in the center of it vertically.

The CSS animation displays a hidden element named `'blur'` which is basically a background color block that takes up the width and height of the image. *On hover* `"blur"` appears on top of the `<img/>` tag inside of the `inner_container` div.

Unfortunately the block element `"blur"` is placed over the top of the the image tag using :

```
"position : relative / position : absolute"
```

causing it to interfere with the `display : inline-block` used to align the `inner_container` div with the `outer_container` div.

I'm looking for a solution that would allow the hidden element to be displayed on top of the `<img/>` tag in the `inner_container` div without using

```
"position : relative / position : absolute"
```

so that I can still align the `inner_container` div inside of the `outer_container` div.

The actual page code can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/zawiqarijo/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @Paulie_D jeez paulie you're everywhere...

Comment: when you don't read the terms and conditions of asking questions... [How to Ask...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Give each element a **z-index** value: elements with higher z-index appear 'in front of' elements with a lower z-index.

So :

```
blur{
  z-index:0;
}
img,inner-container{
  z-index:2;
}
```

Not sure, but if you want **outer-container** 'behind' give it a z-index of -2.

Comment: That will only work if you also use `position:relative;` (or `absolute`, or `fixed`, etc), however, that should be fine as that does nothing if you don't set `top` or co (and the others all imply you knew what you were doing with it already).